# A memory view with GUI

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

There is a memory view and with GUI? for example,I want see the value allocated by my C program(`malloc()`) in memory. Maybe a software-tool like Bless Hex Editor, but instead of view binary file,view the memory map. I hope this is clear for your. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any debugger has this functionality, no?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ visualizing memory of variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276696/c-visualizing-memory-of-variable)

Comment: @SethCarnegie: But I want see all memory map,not my program only.

Comment: @TimothyJones: I'm not using Eclipse.

Comment: @Jack. Or C++. My apologies - I was sure this was about C++ when I tagged it. Have you tried searching? A short web search for "visualising memory C" yields some interesting results, which my be useful depending on what platform you're on.

Comment: `OllyDbg` is good for visualising memory maps.

Comment: @TimothyJones:The question is not see C or my application only, is of all memory allocated,by any application.

Comment: @MikeKwan:look like a good solution,but I forget to quote that I'm using linux.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try using a debugger, it is the most fine-tuned way to view your program's memory. Simply place a breakpoint at before the point of interest and it will show you the value of all your local/global variables. If you are trying to view the whole memory of a running program, HxD (a free Hex editor) allows you to open a process's memory (providing you have sufficient privileges) for viewing/editing. Cheat engine works too if you are trying to analyze patterns in the memory.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing all memory allocated (per application). There are several solutions I know.

- You can log every malloc and free and draw them by yourself. Logging can be easy achieved with `mtrace()` (in Glibc on Linux, created to find memory leaks), see e.g. my [innovation nano library mmtrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593284/enable-mtrace-malloc-trace-for-binary-program) or just insert `mtrace()` and `muntrace()` calls into program. Then you will get a text file with format like `@[IP] type address size], where type is + for malloc, - for free, < > for realloc; size is optional. I have a perl grapher of such logs into very huge images.
- I think free [Sun Studio] has this /I'll check it/
- TotalView (was also sold separately as MemoryScope) from Totalview, now RogueWave. http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview/memoryscape.aspx